# Unable to get Cassandra in a Docker to talk to cluster

Tags: cassandra, docker

Trying to get Cassandra running in a docker using the official docker image. When I execute the below lines of code it starts then stops the docker without connecting to the cluster. I have checked the `cassandra.yaml` file and it looks just like the other nodes on my cluster. Same for the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file. The docker can ping all the other computers.

I run the following and a few derivations:

```
docker run --name cassandra -i \
-v /media/mcamp/HDD/Docker/CampgroundContainer1:/var/lib/cassandra \
-e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="192.168.0.114, 192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.106" \
-e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=CampCluster \
-e CASSANDRA_DC=campground-wireless \
-e CASSANDRA_RACK=Docker1 \
-e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch \
-e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true \
-e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2 \
-p 7000:7000 \
 cassandra:latest
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-11-10 03:45:39,428 TokenMetadata.java:498 - Updating topology for all endpoints that have changed
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any seeds
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1415)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:550)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:801)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:666)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:612)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:393)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:600)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689)
ERROR [main] 2017-11-10 03:46:08,466 CassandraDaemon.java:706 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1415) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:550) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:801) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:666) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:612) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:393) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:600) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-11-10 03:46:08,469 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-11-10 03:46:08,469 Gossiper.java:1540 - No local state, state is in silent shutdown, or node hasn't joined, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-11-10 03:46:08,469 MessagingService.java:984 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/172.17.0.2] 2017-11-10 03:46:08,470 MessagingService.java:1338 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-11-10 03:46:09,653 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
```

Comment: I correctly understand that other Cassandra nodes are in Docker on other computers?

Comment: the other nodes are currently on other computers but not currently in dockers..

Comment: Do you expect to reach the 192 network of the host from the 172 in the container? I doubt that's going to work.

Comment: 192 network should be reachable from inside container (just re-checked from my own containers), but not vice versa...

Comment: I would think they are reachable.. I can ping everything from the containers.. haven't gone the other way though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem could be that you don't set the `CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS` parameter that is used by Cassandra when it talks with other nodes. By default it sets it to value of `CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS`, but in  your case this address is address of Docker network, so other nodes won't able to reach your Docker instance.

You need to set `CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS` to IP address of your machine that hosts the Docker.

Comment: ok I'll try that when I get home.. what would I set that to? set it to the host machine IP or set it to the container IP?

Comment: You need to set it to IP of host machine, so other nodes could reach it